# MariaDB regexp_replace backreference not working as expected

Tags: mariadb, regexp-replace, backreference

I have this simple regex in a user defined function

```
set mm = regexp_replace(in_str, '^M([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?).*$', '\\1');
```

when passing in 'M56-5' in MariaDB 10.1 I would get "56" as expected but in MariaDB 10.4 I get an error "Data truncated for column 'mm' at row 1".  When I pass in 'M56.5' I get "56.5" in both versions as expected.  Did something change?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I mistakenly was using a single backslash to escape the "." whereas it is required to use 2 backslashes when escaping special characters, one for the MariaDB parser and one for the regex library.  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/regular-expressions-overview/#escaping

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> SELECT regexp_replace('M56-5 foo', '^M([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?).*$', '$1');
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| regexp_replace('M56-5 foo', '^M([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?).*$', '$1') |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| 56-5                                                          |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

(That is using MySQL 8.0.31 -- There has been some inconsistencies lately in the syntax of regexps for MySQL and MariaDB versions.)